# VBA - SendKeys Paste Syntax Error - While replacing excel cells

Tags: vba, excel, paste, sendkeys

I'm trying to use SendKeys to copy a word from one cell into the replace (CTRL+F) function.

The copy bit is fine but this spreadsheet is going to be used as a template so the variable is what is in that cell meaning i'm using send keys.

I'm open to other ideas.

Code is below.

```
  Range("E5:G5").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("New Project Schedule").Select
Selection.Replace What:="New Merchant", Replacement:= SendKeys "^v" , LookAt= _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Sheets("Out of Scope").Select
Selection.Replace What:="New Merchant", Replacement:= SendKeys "^v", LookAt= _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Sheets("New Project Schedule").Select
Selection.Replace What:="Merchant", Replacement:= SendKeys "^v", LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Sheets("Out of Scope").Select
Selection.Replace What:="Merchant", Replacement:= SendKeys "^v", LookAt:=
    xlPart , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jason, what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: a) what is in E5:G5? These are cells across three columns. Are they connected? Do the contain ONE text value? b) don't use SendKeys, don't use Selection. Please state exactly what is in E5:G5. I'm sure there's a whole lotta better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to copy and paste - something like this should do:

```
Dim avSheets, vSheet
Dim sWord                 As String

avSheets = Array("New Project Schedule", "Out of Scope")

sWord = Range("E5:G5").Value

For Each vSheet In avSheets
    With Sheets(vSheet).Cells
        .Replace What:="New Merchant", Replacement:=sWord, _
                 LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                 SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        .Replace What:="Merchant", Replacement:=sWord, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
Next vSheet
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than **copying** the block of three cells and then trying to determine where to paste them is different worksheets, get the three cells into an array and then decide where the array should be deposited in each of the other sheets.